# Conflicting values with xarray.Dataset.mean?

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I'm having some trouble understanding the `xarray.Dataset.mean()` method. I'm seeing conflicting values for what I think is the same data.

I have a `Dataset` (`ds`) and in it a `DataArray` (`temp`). I'm trying to summarize values over a `time` dimension, by `x` and `y` dimensions:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

...

>>> sl = slice("2008-05-16T00:00:00", "2008-05-23T23:59:59")
>>> ds.sel(time=sl,  x=0, y=np.arange(5)).mean("time")["temp"].values

array([278.21494, 278.64893, 278.94373, 278.50354, 278.69644],
      dtype=float32)
```

I assumed these values should match the following, but they don't:

```
>>>for i in np.arange(5):
>>>    print(ds.sel(time=sl, x=0, y=i).mean("time")["temp"].values)

278.21484
278.64893
278.9438
278.50357
278.6965
```

These are the equal to the values from using `np.mean()` on the underlying data:

```
>>>for i in np.arange(5):
>>>    print(np.mean(ds.sel(time=sl, x=0, y=i)["temp"].values))
278.21484
278.64893
278.9438
278.50357
278.6965
```

Any idea what's happening here? What am I missing?

EDIT: As @Keisuke points out, the data type appears to be the issue. I was able to get a reproducible example by making an array and setting the datatype to `np.float32`:

```
>>>np.random.seed(907)
>>>arr = np.random.rand(1000, 300, 300).astype(np.float32)
>>>x = np.arange(300)
>>>y = np.arange(300)
>>>z = np.arange(1000)

>>>ds = xr.Dataset({"v": (['z', "y", "x"], arr)},
>>>                coords={'y': y, 'x': x, 'z': z})

>>>arr = ds.mean("z")["v"].values
>>>for i in np.arange(5):
>>>    print(ds.sel(x=i, y=0).mean("z")["v"].values - arr[0,i])
-3.2782555e-07
6.556511e-07
-5.9604645e-08
0.0
-2.682209e-07
```

Note: there are more "minimal" workable examples that can be achieved by using a smaller starting array. However, I noticed that there seem to be more and larger discrepancies the larger the initial array gets (e.g., 1e-6 or -7, vs the seldom 1e-8 with small arrays (~10 elements)). Maybe this was just chance, or maybe I'm going looney. Anyhow, this more closely fits the structure I am working with.

So, still looking for an answer to what's going on, and need to explore whether one of the "methods" in my case is more correct than the other. But this update should lead to a better solution.

Comment: Do you have a reproducible example? I couldn't reproduce this phenomenon. Since your first result has np.float32 dtype, it might be a source of the problem.

Comment: @Keisuke You sly dog, you! I think this is the key! See edit to question with reproducible example, hope it works for you.